# TSQL NOLOCK VIEW and stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, nolock

In our company we tend to use views and stored procedures.

We've recently started to implement the `NOLOCK` statement to a lot of our views.

I was wondering:  if I am applying `NOLOCK` to a view, it "trickles down" to the stored procedure

Say I have a view called `viewPartyPackage` and view statement was...

```
SELECT   
    PartyPackageID, Name, Created, LastModified, Deleted 
FROM        
    dbo.PartyPackage WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE     
    (Deleted = 0)
```

and also I had a stored procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[partypackage_Select]
    (@PartyPackageID bigint = null) 
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [viewPartyPackage] PartyPackage 
    WHERE (@PartyPackageID IS NULL OR @PartyPackageID = [PartyPackageID])
```

Would I lose the NOLOCK feature because I'm calling from a stored procedure and in turn would I need to put a (NOLOCK) on the stored procedure as well? Or does the NOLOCK that's in the view come into play?

Comment: If you want to use this throughout, use `SET TRANSACTION READ UNCOMMITTED` at the start. Does your company know the risks of using `NOLOCK`? i.e. you can get incorrect numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311429/using-with-nolock-table-hint-in-query-using-view-does-it-propagate-within-the-v) to this SO question. To quote:

> See [Table Hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373(SQL.90).aspx)  in MSDN: "In SQL Server 2005, all lock hints are propagated to all the tables and views that are referenced in a view. Also, SQL Server performs the corresponding lock consistency checks."

Comment: sorry to repeat the question on this post. 

What about the other way round: 
if theres a NOLOCKon the store proc and the view didn't have the NOLOCK?

Comment: @Mike - stored procedures do not have NOLOCK defined. They may define NOLOCK on the tables/views they call.

Answer (score 1):

The NOLOCK in the view will take effect no matter where the view is called from.

Comment: How about the other way round? if the NOLOCK was on the store proc and the view didn't have the NOLOCK?

Comment: If you select from the view with NOLOCK in a stored procedure, it will use NOLOCK for that specific call... but it wouldn't magically make the view always use NOLOCK.